# Why does Python's hash of infinity have the digits of π?

Tags: python, math, hash, floating-point, pi

The hash of infinity in Python has digits matching [pi](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pi):

```
>>> inf = float('inf')
>>> hash(inf)
314159
>>> int(math.pi*1e5)
314159
```

Is that just a coincidence or is it intentional?

Comment: Not certain, but my guess would be that it's as deliberate as `hash(float('nan'))` being `0`.

Comment: Hmm, no mention about that in [`sys.hash_info`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/sys.html#sys.hash_info). Easter egg?

Comment: Seems like someone was in a frivolous mood one day. But -- why not?

Comment: Ask Tim Peters. Here's the commit where he introduced this constant, 19 years ago: https://github.com/python/cpython/commit/39dce29365d287dc6b353b2a527dc11fe58dcfa6. I kept those special values when I reworked the numeric hash in https://bugs.python.org/issue8188

Comment: @MarkDickinson  Thanks.  It looks like Tim may have also used the digits of [e](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/E_(mathematical_constant)) for hash of -inf originally.

Comment: @wim Ah yes, true. And apparently I changed that to `-314159`. I'd forgotten about that.

Answer (score 50, accepted):

`_PyHASH_INF` is [defined as a constant](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/35d5068928ab5485e5f28b60b1e33062bc2c46cc/Include/pyhash.h#L31) equal to `314159`.

I can't find any discussion about this, or comments giving a reason.  I think it was chosen more or less arbitrarily.  I imagine that as long as they don't use the same meaningful value for other hashes, it shouldn't matter.

Comment: Small nitpick: it is almost inevitable by definition that the same value will be used for other hashes, e.g. in this case `hash(314159)` is also `314159`. Also try, in Python 3, `hash(2305843009214008110) == 314159` (this input is `314159 + sys.hash_info.modulus`) etc.

Comment: @ShreevatsaR I just meant that as long as they don't choose this value to be the hash of other values by definition, then choosing a meaningful value like this doesn't increase the chance of hash collisions

Answer (score 229):

Summary: It's not a coincidence; [`_PyHASH_INF` is hardcoded as 314159](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/a5119e7d75c9729fc36c059d05f3d7132e7f6bb4/Include/pyhash.h#L29) in the default CPython implementation of Python, and was picked as an arbitrary value (obviously from the digits of π) [by Tim Peters in 2000](https://github.com/python/cpython/commit/39dce29365d287dc6b353b2a527dc11fe58dcfa6#diff-b1b488004963172ac81a4a8127ecfd23R560).

---

The value of `hash(float('inf'))` is one of the system-dependent parameters of the built-in hash function for numeric types, and [is also available](https://docs.python.org/3/library/sys.html#sys.hash_info) as `sys.hash_info.inf` in Python 3:

```
>>> import sys
>>> sys.hash_info
sys.hash_info(width=64, modulus=2305843009213693951, inf=314159, nan=0, imag=1000003, algorithm='siphash24', hash_bits=64, seed_bits=128, cutoff=0)
>>> sys.hash_info.inf
314159
```

(Same results [with PyPy](https://tio.run/##NYwxCsAgDEV3T9FRh7r0QOKgGNAkaJacPpVit/fh/ccqjfC5WVnNYDBNuZYud5B7lkpzOJ6A4v8Z@fulbfUyCkoWIPQhHG8XYsurJcBKwewF) too.)

---

In terms of code, [`hash`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#hash) is a built-in function. Calling it on a Python float object invokes the function whose pointer is given by the [`tp_hash` attribute](https://docs.python.org/3/c-api/typeobj.html#c.PyTypeObject.tp_hash) of the built-in float type (`PyTypeObject PyFloat_Type`), which [is](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/a5119e7d75c9729fc36c059d05f3d7132e7f6bb4/Objects/floatobject.c#L1910,L1924) the `float_hash` function, [defined](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/a5119e7d75c9729fc36c059d05f3d7132e7f6bb4/Objects/floatobject.c#L528,L532) as `return _Py_HashDouble(v->ob_fval)`, which in turn [has](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/a5119e7d75c9729fc36c059d05f3d7132e7f6bb4/Python/pyhash.c#L93-L94)

```c
    if (Py_IS_INFINITY(v))
        return v > 0 ? _PyHASH_INF : -_PyHASH_INF;
```

where `_PyHASH_INF` is [defined as](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/a5119e7d75c9729fc36c059d05f3d7132e7f6bb4/Include/pyhash.h#L29) 314159:

```c
#define _PyHASH_INF 314159
```

---

In terms of history, the first mention of `314159` in this context in the Python code (you can find this with `git bisect` or `git log -S 314159 -p`) was added by [Tim Peters](https://en.wikipedia.org/w/index.php?title=Tim_Peters_(software_engineer)&oldid=886078303) in August 2000, in what is now  commit [39dce293](https://github.com/python/cpython/commit/39dce29365d287dc6b353b2a527dc11fe58dcfa6) in the `cpython` git repository.

The commit message says:

> Fix for http://sourceforge.net/bugs/?func=detailbug&bug_id=111866&group_id=5470.
>   This was a misleading bug -- the true "bug" was that `hash(x)` gave an error
>   return when `x` is an infinity.  Fixed that.  Added new `Py_IS_INFINITY` macro to
>   `pyport.h`.  Rearranged code to reduce growing duplication in hashing of float and
>   complex numbers, pushing Trent's earlier stab at that to a logical conclusion.
>   Fixed exceedingly rare bug where hashing of floats could return -1 even if there
>   wasn't an error (didn't waste time trying to construct a test case, it was simply
>   obvious from the code that it *could* happen).  Improved complex hash so that
>   `hash(complex(x, y))` doesn't systematically equal `hash(complex(y, x))` anymore.

In particular, in this commit he ripped out the code of `static long float_hash(PyFloatObject *v)` in `Objects/floatobject.c` and made it just `return _Py_HashDouble(v->ob_fval);`, and in the definition of `long _Py_HashDouble(double v)` in `Objects/object.c` he added the lines:

```c
        if (Py_IS_INFINITY(intpart))
            /* can't convert to long int -- arbitrary */
            v = v < 0 ? -271828.0 : 314159.0;
```

So as mentioned, it was an arbitrary choice. Note that 271828 is formed from the first few decimal digits of [e](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/e_(mathematical_constant)).

Related later commits:

- [By Mark Dickinson in Apr 2010](https://github.com/python/cpython/commit/f3eeca16cbadd7da5836ed781572343863b1a074) ([also](https://github.com/python/cpython/commit/ac256ab2843dfb6c28af0227202df67664ed462e)), making the `Decimal` type behave similarly
- [By Mark Dickinson in Apr 2010](https://github.com/python/cpython/commit/5e0c2748fb2e16b3b0f33f0bb55f1aaa1272f887) ([also](https://github.com/python/cpython/commit/5daab45158094e577b9791cda7d8a0f4e34f45cb)), moving this check to the top and adding test cases
- [By Mark Dickinson in May 2010](https://github.com/python/cpython/commit/dc787d2055a7b562b64ca91b8f1af6d49fa39f1c) as [issue 8188](https://bugs.python.org/issue8188), completely rewriting the hash function to [its current implementation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#hashing-of-numeric-types), but retaining this special case, giving the constant a name `_PyHASH_INF` (also removing the 271828 which is why in Python 3 `hash(float('-inf'))` returns `-314159` rather than `-271828` as it does in Python 2)
- [By Raymond Hettinger in Jan 2011](https://github.com/python/cpython/commit/e7dfe74ce39cad736da8e3a24fdc4cfb50c7c515), adding an explicit example in the "What's new" for Python 3.2 of `sys.hash_info` showing the above value. (See [here](https://docs.python.org/3/whatsnew/3.2.html#decimal-and-fractions).)
- [By Stefan Krah in Mar 2012](https://github.com/python/cpython/commit/1919b7e72bc43315b32f38a6f5f01e8c717907f4) modifying the Decimal module but keeping this hash.
- [By Christian Heimes in Nov 2013](https://github.com/python/cpython/commit/985ecdcfc29adfc36ce2339acf03f819ad414869), moved the definition of `_PyHASH_INF` from `Include/pyport.h` to `Include/pyhash.h` where it now lives.

Comment: The choice of -271828 for -Inf eliminates any doubt that the pi association was accidental.

Comment: @RussellBorogove No but it makes it about one million times less likely ;)

Comment: @cmaster: See the part above where it says May 2010, namely the documentation section on [hashing of numeric types](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#hashing-of-numeric-types) and [issue 8188](https://bugs.python.org/issue8188) — the idea is that we want `hash(42.0)` to be the same as `hash(42)`, also the same as `hash(Decimal(42))` and `hash(complex(42))` and `hash(Fraction(42, 1))`. The solution (by Mark Dickinson) is an elegant one IMO: defining a mathematical function that works for any rational number, and using the fact that floating-point numbers are rational numbers too.

Comment: @ShreevatsaR Ah, thank you. While I would not have cared to guarantee these equalities, it's good to know that there is a good, solid, and logical explanation for the seemingly complex code :-)

Comment: @cmaster  Actually, that's a necessity.  Hashable objects which compare equal must have the same hash value.

Comment: @cmaster The hash function for integers is simply `hash(n) = n % M` where M = (2^61 - 1). This is generalized for rational n to `hash(p/q) = (p/q) mod M` with the division being interpreted modulo M (in other words: `hash(p/q) = (p * inverse(q, M)) % M`). The reason we want this: if into a dict `d` we put `d[x] = foo` and then we have `x==y` (e.g. 42.0==42) but `d[y]` is not the same as `d[x]`, then we'd have a problem. Most of the seemingly complex code comes from the nature of the floating-point format itself, to recover the fraction properly and needing special-cases for inf and NaN values.

Answer (score 13):

Indeed,

```
sys.hash_info.inf
```

returns `314159`. The value is not generated, it's built into the source code.
In fact,

```
hash(float('-inf'))
```

returns `-271828`, or approximately -e, in python 2 ([it's -314159 now](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#hashing-of-numeric-types)).

The fact that the two most famous irrational numbers of all time are used as the hash values makes it very unlikely to be a coincidence.